# Relationship between two kinds of classifications of Riemann surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces

There are two kinds of classifications of Riemann surfaces.

Classification 1: Let $M$ be a Riemann surface. We will call $M$:

- *elliptic* iff $M$ is compact (= closed);
- *parabolic* iff $M$ is not compact and $M$ doesn't carry a negative non-constant subharmonic function;
- *hyperbolic* iff $M$ does carry a negative non-constant subharmonic function.

Classification 2: Let $M$ be a Riemann surface. Let $\tilde{M}$ be the universal covering surface of $M$. We'll call $M$:

- *elliptic* iff $\tilde{M}$ is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^2$;
- *parabolic* iff $\tilde{M}$ is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{C}$;
- *hyperbolic* iff $\tilde{M}$ is
  conformally equivalent to the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$.

I want to know, what's the relationship between these two classifications?  How to characterize an elliptic/parabolic/hyperbolic surface $M$ in the sense of the first classification by the corresponding Fuchsian group (I mean when $M=\mathbb{D}/\Gamma$ for some Fuchsian group $\Gamma$)?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  I think you swapped the terms “elliptic” and “parabolic”.  Also on your first definition, something is wrong.  Did you mean to write that $\tilde{M}$ is compact?

Comment: The question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369379/elliptic-parabolic-and-hyperbolic-riemann-surfaces-classification?rq=1 has a reference for Classification 1 and an illuminating answer by Eremenko.

Comment: @JasonStarr  The first definition is copied from the book of Farkas and Kra, "Riemann Surfaces 2nd", on page178. I'm not familar with this definition. It seems to be used frequently in geometric analysis. However, in topology, a surface is usually said to be hyperbolic if and only if it carries a hyperbolic metric, which coincides with the second definition.  I want to know whether we can characterize a surface of elliptic/parabolic/hyperbolic type in the sense of the first definition by the corresponding Fuchsian group, since it's a common way to define a surface by a Fuchsian group.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Thanks. I know this post and it helps a lot.

Answer (score 4):

These classifications coincide for simply connected Riemann surfaces. In general, an open parabolic surface in the second sense is also parabolic in the first sense, but not vice versa. In fact there are only two open parabolic Riemann surfaces in the second sense: the plane and the punctured plane, and they are easily seen to be parabolic in the first sense.

The simplest example of a surface parabolic in the first sense but not in the second sense is a sphere with finitely many $\geq 3$ punctures.
For many other examples of parabolic surfaces in the first sense, other than the plane and punctured plane, see,
for example, the book of M. Tsuji, Potential theory in modern function theory (Maruzen, Tokyo, 1959, there is an reprint published by Chelsea), Chap. X.

In fact, there are more than two different ways to classify open Riemann surfaces, see Tsuji's book.

Another book which contains a classification open Riemann surfaces is Ahlfors and Sario, Riemann surfaces, and this one is freely available:
https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/lars-v-ahlfors-l-sario-riemann-surfaces.pdf

Comment: I didn't read this book. Thank you!

Comment: In terms of looking it up, I think the reprint of the Tsuji book was by Chelsea before AMS acquired them ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=414898)).

Comment: @LSpice: thanks, I did not know this. Corrected.